# How Many Projects Can I Have in the Spark Version of Firebase?

Tags: firebase

I'm trying to add a 3rd project but I keep getting this error, "**You have exceeded the maximum number of free projects that you can create. Try deleting some projects via Project settings or request a project limit increase.**"

I have deleted all excess projects via Project settings in hopes of removing this error but it persists. I don't want to request more projects and have to pay.

I thought I could have at least 5 projects in the free, Spark account?

Comment: Please pay more attention when you tag. Apache spark has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Will do @FrankvanPuffelen. First time poster here.

Comment: Do you also Google Cloud projects (on cloud.google.com/console)? When those have no associated billing account, such projects will also count towards your maximum.

Comment: I received a message from support saying that after deleting a project, it will take 7 days to fully remove it from your account. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah good one, I keep forgetting that (because I don't delete a lot of projects).

Comment: @Coder828 This is confusing. Your question is about Firebase Spark plan and in the answer you have posted link from Google API Console. Here ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/41498452/1199154 ) it doesn't say anything about project limit being 10. Kindly recheck and update your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Free accounts are allowed to create up to 10 projects.

Find your projects list here: https://console.developers.google.com

Once you delete a project from your list, it will take 7 days to be completely removed from your account. If you've reached your 10 project maximum, you won't be able to add a new project until after those 7 days.