# How many free projects can you have in firebase?

Tags: firebase

I initially had 6 projects created in google firebase and, recently, I wanted to create my next one for which I got a screan informing me that I have reached the limit of the number of firebase projects that I can have.

"No problem.", I said. And went on deleting one of them but when I tried to create a new one, again, I was greated with the same message.

I refreshed the page but that didn't fix it.

Can someone tell me what is the maximum number of free projects that one can have in Firebase? I was not able to find this info anywhere.

Comment: I couldn't see any word on the limit of projects one can create in the firebase docs, but I guess it is unlimited. If you're having questions, you might wanna ask the support team, it might be a bug, or something else. The support guys are good!

Comment: There is no fixed number. It depends on the "standing" of your account. But after deleting a project, it takes a week before it is really gone (and thus freed up to create a new one). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949974/how-many-projects-can-i-have-in-the-spark-version-of-firebase and Adarsh' answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501794/limitation-of-free-plan-in-firebase/38450025#38450025

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you. I didn't know that.