# Firebase maximum projects and apps

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

How many applications can I create in one project from a single account and how many projects I can create in Firebase for Cloud Messaging?

Comment: It's most likely 8 projects as far as I know.

Comment: The answer for "How many projects I can create in Firebase for Cloud Messaging" (using free account) seems to be changing always.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Update from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50351827/4625829):

> There is indeed a quota on how many apps can be created in a project. The exact number depends on multiple factors, but it typically is in the lower 30s.
>
> The quota cannot be changed, nor is it increased for paid projects.

---

> *How many applications can I create in one project from a single account?*

I don't think there isn't any limit on how many apps you can link to a single project. AFAIK, I think it is actually *encouraged* for apps that  are related when it comes to the Firebase services to be linked to a single project.

> *How many projects I can create in Firebase for Cloud Messaging?*

I'm not sure what you mean for the *for Cloud Messaging* part, but I'm pretty sure that every project you create can be used for FCM. Anyways, I think it'd be safe to refer to the comment by @FrankvanPuffelen on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38120044/4625829):

> There's no limit on the number of projects in general, but there is a limit on the number of projects on an unpaid plan. The exact limit for that varies, from what I understand.

PS: As per looking around the docs, I'm fairly sure that there is nothing explicitly mentioned/stated in the official documentation that can clearly answer your questions.

Comment: I contacted to Firebase Support and they have responded with the exact same answer as above.

Comment: @AL. Since you wrote this answer, we introduced a limit on the number of apps per project. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50345479/firebase-project-max-number-of-apps

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen I'll update my answer and tag this post as a duplicate.

Comment: It was just the part about the number of apps per project that got outdated. The rest of your answer was actually still valid as far as I could see.

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't able to go through the post. I'll update.

Answer (score 47):

### As of now (8 Dec 2017) I got a maximum of 5 projects

I got this message when I was creating new project and only had my 2 existing projects.

> You're 3 projects away from the project limit.

I occasionally create a new Firebase project to test and learn its new features such as Firestore and Cloud Functions and then delete the project. Last month I tried creating a new project to learn Firestore and only had 2 existing projects, I've never got any project-limit message like this before. I think Firebase team just changed the project limit to 5 recently

[image: Firebase limit 5 projects]

### Update 8 March 2018

My account reached the limit. I tried request another 10 projects to Firebase team and it took 1 business day to approve (sometimes it might take longer). I have to say that Firebase team is not mean. They are willing to help if they can.

I request a project limit increase and say I want another 10 projects because I'm starting my new startup(MVP) and want to keep the cost low at first. After the business generate money I will pay for Paid Services. Besides I told them how easy I can reach the limit as I have to create new projects to test Firebase features, like Firestore and Cloud Messaging before using the features in production. And finally they gave me another 10 projects :)

**If you want to start a business with Firebase and have already reached the limit then Firebase team is going to help and give you project limit increase as long as you're not a spammer.**

Comment: How did you approach them?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. If you reach the limit, there will be a button show up on the screen which you can use to submit project limit increase request.

Comment: does deleting older test projects free up the limit? i made one test project and deleted it. did i just waste one project?

Comment: deleting existing projects doesn't free up the limit. If you plan to use Firebase/Firestore for your business, I recommend to request the project limit increase. They're eager to help you grow your business...hope you have good luck.

Comment: Google/Firebase seems extremely willing to grant quota increases. I requested a quota increase of 10 projects on 6/26/20 and was approved 3 minutes later, even though I said in my request that I'm only intending to use their free services.

Answer (score 23):

I just searched this because I was watching a video which hinted that you can only have 6 free projects:

https://youtu.be/VUNkjQ_k2Uc?t=1m21s

It has three created and says you can create 3 more. The video was recorded/uploaded 13 Jul 2017.

[image: 3 projects from limit]

I guess it wouldn't take much to confirm this if you just created six test accounts.

Comment: I currently have 4 and it won't let me create a 5th. Perhaps it varies?

Comment: I have 2 and wasn't allowed a third. It definitely varies ... or their algorithm doesn't like me!

Comment: I already have 11 projects, and am allowed 2 more. Didn't request for more yet.

Answer (score 8):

When I created 8th project on firebase it showed me a warning stating "You are 3 projects away from the project limit". This means I can have maximum 10 projects. I couldn't find any official documentation regarding this. So, I guess we can have maximum of 10 projects only. 
If you want to have more project after your limit has exhausted, instead of creating new projects you can add any number of apps (ios, android & web) to an similar existing project.

Answer (score 7):

When we were unable to add new apps to our project, we contacted their support and this was their answer:

> After consulting this to our engineers, I've found out that there is a
>   hard limit of 1000 apps which can be added per project. This can no
>   longer be raised, unfortunately.

Comment: While this answers the first part of the question, it misses the part about how many projects.

Comment: This became 30 ios app max

Answer (score 3):

Cloud Platform Console Help has a page here: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6330231 which answers some of your queries.

Here's an extract:

> "If you attempt to exceed your project limit, the console will prompt you to fill out a request form. This happens when you try to create a project but you have already reached your quota. The form will require you to specify the number of additional projects you need, along with their corresponding email accounts, billing accounts, and intended uses."

Best practices when requesting more projects are also listed.

Answer (score 3):

**[2021]** Firebase's a part of google cloud, so the limit is **12 Project** as a Free plan (non-billed account, that's means I didn't active the free 300$ that come from Google Cloud) and ***I think it's (30 Project) at all time as shown **[HERE](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/limits)** but I never used the paid plan or active the trail*** ...

So check your google cloud [account](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager), you will see all the projects that you have! but there are some notes you can take into consideration:

**- Note 1: I opened a new Gmail account and try to make 13 projects he stopped on project 12, But the problem is after deleting your project you need to wait 30 days then you can replace it with another one**, there is a modal show the date of delete completely after request that.
[image]

**- Note 2: When you create a new project from firebase will create a project in Google Cloud,** also you can add the google cloud project to your firebase account.

> When you create a new Firebase project in the Firebase console, you're
> creating a Google Cloud project.

[image]

**Go to the google cloud to make my 13th project**... this message appeared to me:
[image]

**Also I have it in Firebase**... this message appeared to me:
[image]

**- Note 3: Don't forget! Sometimes that happened! when you using also Google API and create a project it also creates a project on google cloud so you will consume the quotas limit**.

**- Note 4: You can add the exacting project in Google cloud however from where the project was created to your firebase account.**

> In Summary: the Firebase/Google API's projects are Google Cloud
> Projects behind the scene that limited to 12 projects for the
> non-billed account and you can request more, so you have 12 projects maybe all of them firebase or google API or google cloud or a mix of them but you can't exceed 12 projects in total without requesting an increase.

Answer (score 2):

**10 oct 2020**

Today i tried to create another project, I only had two projects and I decided to remove one, then I tried to create another project and I got the message of the limit. I just send a request for 10 projects honestly. After a minutes I decided create another project and again I have two projects.. The limit to this date is **2 projects.**

Comment: It takes one month for a project to be permanently deleted in case you change your mind and want to restore it. You can see your projects at https://console.firebase.google.com/iam-admin/projects

Answer (score 1):

As 2017-12-15, the limit (for my account at least) seems to be 12. (before creating my 10th project, it said I had 3 left)

Odd that the limit seems to be different per account. (either that, or they updated it since @Pakpoom's answer)

Answer (score 1):

**12/23/2021**

I also got the same message and I have requested another 10 projects from the Firebase team to experiment with Firebase services for my future Flutter/Firebase projects. They have allowed/given **10 projects within a few mins**. Thank you, Awesome Firebase Team.

Answer (score 1):

I think It's 10 projects. I have already created 9 projects and now it shows I'm one project away from maximum limit. [image]

Answer (score 0):

About your second question

> how many projects I can create in Firebase for Cloud Messaging?

For the Free plan, you can read this FAQ
https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6330231?hl=en
It doesn't actually say how many, but explains how you can request more if necessary.