# Maxiumum number of apps one can Create in Firebase Console (Uder Free Plan)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-console

I have about 200-300 apps on playstore. I wanted to connect them to Firebase Service mainly for 2 things as below:

1. Send Push Notifications occasionly to each app individually
2. Use Remote Config to store App Constants (Hardly 1 or 2 keys for each app)

So, my questions are:

1. How many Projects I can create on Firebase Console under Free Plan.
2. Should I create Single Project and add all my apps in it OR Create individual project for each app. (I have about 200 apps)
3. What is maximum no. of notification one can send using firebase (free)?

I searched for this but cannot get exact answer. Aslo contacted firebase team but no response yet.

Comment: The maximum project has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41498452/4112725). And the push notification is unlimited, I think, but I'm not sure

Comment: Thanks @koceeng :) That helped me. Just wanted your input on this: I will create a single project in firebase and add all my apps in it (around 200)      Also, each app will have 2-3 Remote Config values. Is this a correct way to implement?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but 200 app in single Firebase project is too much I think. Let's both wait for someone who have knowledge on this

Comment: @koceeng Check my answer below. And thanks for your help. Now I am thinking about deviding my apps in groups of 25-30 and creating 1 project for each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have asked this query to Firebase Support and they responded me as below:

1. How many Projects I can create on Firebase Console under Free Plan.

   - The maximum number of free projects is dynamic, and depends on a specific account. And for the paid projects, the limit is really high. The default quota per account depends on certain factors but I can't disclose them explicitly due to a potential for abuse. Sorry about that.
2. Should I create Single Project and add all my apps in it OR Create individual project for each app. (I have about 200 apps)

   - You could add them in only one project. However, it's probably not a good practice to add a large number of apps in one project. This may result to performance problems while loading the Firebase console. In order to avoid that situation, you might want to consider breaking those up into different projects.