# What is the purpose of creating different applications under same project in Firebase console?

Tags: android, firebase-console, google-play-services

I wonder what is the main purpose of creating different applications under same project in firebase console as it does not allow to have different package name. I need separate package name for around 20 mobile applications in android for push notifications(google-services.json). Can somebody guide me how to do that in FCM under same account(gmail). 
Thank you.

Comment: I think the main reason is, in a firebase console, you can create maximum 8 Projects, and in that Projects you can have multiple applications.

Comment: How to use same package and google-services.json file for different applications if I create under one project. As playstore needs different package names for different applications.

Answer (score 2):

Different applications in one firebase project *can* (or must?) have different package names.
If you want to use push notifications, they will all have the same server key. But you can filter on package name or registration token so it's definitely manageable on your server side.

Alternatively you could make multiple projects, one for each. But note that there is a project limit you might hit. This limit is not the same for everyone, based on account activity and such, and you can request more projects when you reach it.

Comment: Do they allow to increase project limit free-of-cost?

Comment: Not always. You'll have to contact support and they manually approve the request. From what I've read this is based on amount of payed cloud services used and age of the account, probably among others. Some source links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485736/firebase-maximum-projects-and-apps), [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/ltmyg5e9jAA) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/wYQH_2uEPyI)

Answer (score 0):

for ex: generally if we develop any app in 3 different platforms 
like android,iOS,windows.
we have to create 3 different applications in single project.
then only firebase data will sync and push notifications will work.(server key/project id should mentain same)