# Firebase project max number of apps

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have created a project in the `Firebase` console where I have added 33 apps (`Android` and `iOS`). When I try to add the 34 I am getting the following error message:

[image]

The problem is that I don't really want to cleanup or delete any of the existing apps / `OAuth 2.0` clients since I need them.

So how can I increase that quota of 33 apps per projects ? Right now I am using the free tier of `Firebase`. Would the quota change if I upgrade to some of the premium subscriptions ?

Comment: That's strange because i have a project in firebase which has 34 apps currently and no warning coming if i add another one. you might wanna contact to firebase team for this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is indeed a quota on how many apps can be created in a project. The exact number depends on multiple factors, but it typically is in the lower 30s.

The quota cannot be changed, nor is it increased for paid projects.

Comment: is this documented anywhere?

Comment: actually I have right now running 89 apps in a single project for notification.

Comment: frank, is there a way to disable a project but not delete it? so the active # of projects is still within the limit?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to disable a project without deleting it.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#apps-per-project

Comment: Thanks for that link Doug. 