# Getting an error while registering new bundle id in firebase having multiple android apps and one iOS apps

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-console

While registering iOS app in Firebase having different bundle id in one project, getting error as shown in screenshot.

> There was an unknown error while processing your request. Try again.

[image]

I tried fresh login, still facing same issue. I also tried different browser but getting same issue.

Suppose I am registering new android app in same project having different bundle id, it is not showing any error. Also 80+ android apps are registered in same project and one iOS app. I want to add another iOS app in same project.

Comment: *firebaser here* "80+ android apps are registered in same project" This means you may have exceeded the limit on the number of apps that can be added to a project. I recommend [reaching out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: hi,i tried another MacBook,and new iOS app is registered successfully.;-)

Comment: Good to hear you got it sorted. In general, just be aware that there is a limit to the number of apps you can have in a project. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50345479/firebase-project-max-number-of-apps

Comment: hi, but now I m registering new app in firebase getting same error. :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation and had only 2 projects so 'reaching out' wasn't the case. I've refreshed the page and the project was already set correctly with my bundle id.