# Firebase Quota Number Of Mobile Apps

Tags: firebase

I added a new app to a firebase project. I have 66 apps already (33 android, 33 ios). The error i get when I hit add app is "An unexpected error has occured. [Reason: Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).]"

According to their docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more

> Number of apps per project
>
> While there is no restriction on the number of apps within a project, adding an app can create one or more underlying OAuth 2.0 client IDs. There is a limit of around 30 client IDs that can be created within a single project.

Interestingly, someone else got a similar error: [Firebase project max number of apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50345479/firebase-project-max-number-of-apps), but in this case it tells them that their oauth has maxed out. I don't get that particular error.

How do I add a new app, or view client IDS, or can I use the same oauths? I need to be able to add a new app to this project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Firebaser here*

It indeed looks like you're hitting the limit on the number of OAuth clients IDs. This means that you can only add new clients IDs, by first removing existing client IDs.

There is a similar limit on the number of apps you can have in a Firebase project, but you don't seem to be hitting that yet. The reason for this limit is that all apps in a project share the Firebase resources of that project, like Analytics, Auth, and more. For that reason the apps in a single project should logically be part of the same business application, e.g. an iOS and an Android version, a Free and a Paid version. You should only combine apps into a single Firebase project if they have such a relation, which makes the 30-something limit quite reasonable.

The easiest way forward if you need to create more apps, is to create another project.

If you can neither remove existing OAuth Client IDs, nor put the additional apps in another project, you may want to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 15):

In case anyone is wondering, removing the apps from the Firebase console doesn't automatically remove the OAuth Client IDs, hence it will not free up the quota. They need to be manually removed from [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using same SHA-1  fingerprint in multiple projects ,then delete it in any of projects added.

In my case I have only 6 apps added in one project and i was getting same error when i try to add new app with same SHA-1.

Answer (score 2):

deleting unused apps from firebase project did not work for me. Also deleted unused "OAuth clients" from the "OAuth 2.0 Client IDs" section at the link below removed that caution.

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials