# The operation has failed(Reason: Resource has been exhausted(e.g. Check quota))

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

Getting error while accepting new google analytics terms of service.The operation has failed(Reason: Resource has been exhausted(e.g. Check quota))
Error image :[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBCaY.png

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue, you need to delete the existing client ID and then add the new one.

For more information check out this link:[Firebase Quota Number Of Mobile Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57874324/firebase-quota-number-of-mobile-apps).

Comment: Has the problem been resolved？

Comment: Thank you for sharing @ Wen xu Li ,No still im facing the same issue. Sent the issue to fiebase console support team. They suggested to me the following way.
Based from similar cases we've received before, this issue occurs when the account exceeds the allowed number of properties. Here’s a potential solution you may try to resolve the error. Please try to delete the properties associated with the Google Analytics account that are not in use as mentioned from this article. Once that's done, check again if you still see the error.
Still im not getting any idea how to fix this issue.
Thanks

Comment: refer to this link: https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#apps-per-project

Comment: I sent mail to firebase support team . They have increased limit from 100 to 200 properties per account.