# How many android apps can be added in one project registered in firebase ?

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, push-notification

I have added 32 android apps in one firebase project. But now when I am trying to add a new app in my project I am getting error below:
   There was an unknown error while processing the request. Try again.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485736/firebase-maximum-projects-and-apps

Comment: Above links are not working. I am still getting same error while adding app to a project