# Firebase: Too many Apps on project

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm unable to create new Android Apps in my Firebase project.

Looking at the Network Tab in the browser shows:

```
POST https://mobilesdk-pa.clients6.google.com/v1/projects/****/clients
```

Results in http status-code 429 with body:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 429,
    "message": "Too many Apps on project:****",
    "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.internal.firebase.v1.ErrorCode",
        "code": 2
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there a way to raise this limit?

**UPDATE:** After contacting the Firebase Support and explaining our case to them, they raised the rate-limit. To which value is unknown so far:

> We made some adjustments to the app limits based on the information
>   we’ve gathered with other developers who are having the same issue. I
>   can’t provide the exact number of apps that you can create from the
>   console at this time, but we’re currently focused on delivering the
>   best possible experience to app developers.

Comment: There is a limit of (last I checked) around the mid-30 apps that can be added to a single project. There is no way to raise that limit. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485736/firebase-maximum-projects-and-apps

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen We already have >300 apps in the project and need add more. Otherwise we can't provide new apps to customers. All was fine until end of last week, so that rate limit must be new.

Comment: The rate limit was introduced a few years ago. It could be that it temporarily wasn't enforced for your project, but I have no way to check that. You might want to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: In general: consider creating a separate project for each customer, as having multiple customers' apps in a single project means that you're mixing the data of their users/devices.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen We don't track any data. We only want to send push notifications. So there is no limit on projects (>1000 projects are fine?)

Comment: There is a limit on the number of free projects, but no limit (that I know off) on paid projects. And since FCM is a free product within Firebase, you won't get charged if you only use FCM on a project on the Blaze plan.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the answer, but how can we create a new Firebase project via API? We don't want to manage hundreds of projects by hand. 
Also, the pricing seems to be linked to particular projects, not to an account.

Comment: In the left-nav of the Firebase documentation, quite near to the top, you'll find `Manage projects programmatically`, and in there links to [use the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest) and the Admin SDKs for [Node.js](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.projectManagement), [Java](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/projectmanagement/package-summary), and [Python](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.project_management).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen We already use REST API to create the apps in projects. We could create Projects (first GCP then addFirebase), but there seems to be no way to retrieve the serverkey, which we need to send the push notifications. So that would be a manual step. Do I miss something?

Comment: I'd expect that to be returned by something like https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/getAdminSdkConfig (given that the Admin SDK can send via FCM), but don't see it listed in the docs.